# Twitter Bootstrap & Spree Project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, spree

How to install and configure twitter-boostrap-rails gem in a spree project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose you can use [github.com/Andrewmp1/spree_bootstrap_theme](http://github.com/Andrewmp1/spree_bootstrap_theme)

P.S
Set up and take a part in colaboration. Now I looking for make working gallery in product#show page.
My shop on TB:
http://vk-magazin.com